# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on SharedPreference with boolean-array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I get thrown the Exception for my boolean-array and I do not know why this is happening. I browsed some websites for a recommendation or a solution for this kind of problem, but I didn't find anything.

That's the reason why I am asking on SO because I had not find a question that addressed the same problem for this typical code. I sit for about 5 Hour to implement SharedPreference.

This is my code which is running on my `PreferenceClass`. I am trying to save the Multichoice input from the User. After I click on the `musicPreference`, the app crashes and I am forced to close it.

```
boolean[] isSelectedMusic;

@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main_settings);

    musikPreference = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_music_key));

    listMusicName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music);
    listMusicId = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music_values);

    isSelectedMusik = new boolean[listMusikName.length];




    /*
        TODO Guck wie sich der Input ändert je nachdem kann man sagen wie man es ändert
     */
    if ((Arrays.equals(getStoredMusik("storedSelectedMusik"), isSelectedMusik))==false) {
        isSelectedMusik = getStoredMusik("storedSelectedMusik");
    }

    musikPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            AlertDialog.Builder musik_dialog_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            musik_dialog_builder.setTitle(R.string.pref_title_musik);
            musik_dialog_builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMusikName, isSelectedMusik, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean is_selected) {
                    if (is_selected) {
                        userMusik.add(position);
                        System.out.println("Position des Items: +" + position);
                    } else {
                        userMusik.remove((Integer.valueOf(position)));
                    }
                }

            });

            musik_dialog_builder.setCancelable(false);
            musik_dialog_builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    String musik = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < userMusik.size(); i++) {
                        musik = musik + listMusikName[userMusik.get(i)];
                        System.out.println("Z.100 - Z.106\n" +
                                "item: " + musik + "\n" +
                                "i: " + i + "\n" +
                                "id:" + listMusikId[i] + "\n");

                        userMusikID.add(listMusikId[i]);
                        userMusikName.add(listMusikName[i]);

                        isSelectedMusik[i] = true;


                        if (i != userMusik.size() - 1) {
                            musik = musik + ", ";
                            System.out.println("Z.108 - Z.112\n" +
                                    "item: " + musik + "\n" +
                                    "i: " + i + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    setMusik(musik);
                    storeSelectedMusik(isSelectedMusik,"storedSelectedMusik");

                }
            });

            private void storeSelectedMusik(boolean[] isSelectedMusikList, String arrayName) {
                SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("DataOfSelectedMusik", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                mEditor.putInt(arrayName + "_size", isSelectedMusikList.length);

                for (int i = 0; i < isSelectedMusikList.length; i++) {
                    mEditor.putBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, isSelectedMusikList[i]);
                }


                mEditor.apply();
            }

            private boolean[] getStoredMusik(String arrayName) {
                SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("DataOfSelectedMusik", 0);
                int size = mSharedPreferences.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
                boolean[] isSelectedMusikArray = new boolean[size];

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    isSelectedMusikArray[i] = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, false);
                }

                return isSelectedMusikArray;
            }
```

That is my Exception what I get on my Logcat.

> 07-19 05:41:56.048 4769-4769/cren.example.com.musiclover E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: cren.example.com.musiclover, PID: 4769
>           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$1.getView(AlertController.java:1101)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2366)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2719)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1545)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1856)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7184)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
length=0
```

means that your array is actually empty. You are trying to get the first element of an empty array.

I don't see immediately from your stacktrace which line throws the Exception, but there are a few `array[index]` calls where it might occur. Here, for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userMusik.size(); i++) {
                        musik = musik + listMusikName[userMusik.get(i)];
                        System.out.println("Z.100 - Z.106\n" +
                                "item: " + musik + "\n" +
                                "i: " + i + "\n" +
                                "id:" + listMusikId[i] + "\n");

                        userMusikID.add(listMusikId[i]);
                        userMusikName.add(listMusikName[i]);
```

You verify you don't exceed the size of `userMusik`, but you don't check whether or not the elements you try to retrieve from `listMusikId` and `listMusikName` exist.

Comment: but it works without the SharedPreference. if we take out the if(Arrays.equals) and the method on the last row storeSelectedMusik() and getStoredMusik(). So like this code what you are pointing at works without SharedPreference. I would add Stacktrace but it doesn't get Display by Android Studio.

Comment: you already did add the stacktrace ... what do you mean you can't show it?
Seeing as I have no idea what your activity is doing, my guess is this: SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("DataOfSelectedMusik", 0);
                is trying to get the first element of an empty array in your getSharedPreferences method. you may want to check that. Seeing as you don't show that method, I can only guess

Comment: Ok Thank you I have fix the Problem.